EventBridge one time schedule expression error
I'm trying to schedule a one time event on AWS EventBridge from my app. I'm using AWS java SDK:
    implementation(platform("software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.20.56"))
    implementation("software.amazon.awssdk:secretsmanager")
    implementation("software.amazon.awssdk:eventbridge")

This is where I schedule the event:
    fun scheduleTask(ruleName: String, scheduledTime: ZonedDateTime) {
        val ruleRequest = PutRuleRequest.builder()
            .name(ruleName)
            .scheduleExpression("at(${scheduledTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"))})")
            .state("ENABLED")
            .build()
        //... rest of the code
    }

The issue here is that the at(yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss) pattern is giving me the following error:

Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid.

But I'm sure that the schedule expression is valid since it's specified in the official AWS docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/UserGuide/schedule-types.html.
Two additional side notes:

I tested with a simple rate(1 minute) expression and it worked fine
I checked the time formatted string in debug and it perfectly matches the one in the doc
What is going on here?


The schedule expression you're providing is a one-time schedule using an at expression. Such expressions are not supported by CloudWatch Events Rule.
As per CloudWatch Events documentation, in event bridge only rate and cron based expressions are supported. EventBridge primarily supports recurring events using cron expressions or fixed rate intervals for scheduled events.
There is one workaround we can develop by disabling the rule after it is executed:
val putRuleRequest = PutRuleRequest.builder()
        .name(ruleName)
        .scheduleExpression("cron(${scheduledTime.minute} ${scheduledTime.hour} ${scheduledTime.dayOfMonth} ${scheduledTime.monthValue} ? ${scheduledTime.year})")
        .state("ENABLED")
        .build()

// Successfully executed

DisableRuleRequest disableRuleRequest = new DisableRuleRequest()
            .withName(ruleName);


However, I would recommend utilize AWS instead if the use case is around executing at-once schedule in response to events.
